# Magento extension installed but not showing up in admin

Tags: magento, installation, admin, extension-methods

I've installed a magento extension and it seems to be installed correctly. I've I check it in Admin->System->Configuration->Advanced It appears Enabled. But The tab is suposed to appear in admin, doesn't appear.

My magento version is 1.7. I've tried some things but nothing works:

- I've cleaned the cache directory and clean the cache in admin
- I've give the hole web directory 777 permisions
- I've reinstall the extension
- I've installed it from magento connect and directly copping the directories and files from github
- I've uninstalled and installed a few times
- I've log out and log in in magento admin

But nothing fix my problem. Has anyone any more ideas?

The extension is SMTP Pro Mail. Here is the system.xml

```
    <config>
  <tabs>
    <aschroder module="smtppro" translate="label">
      <label>Aschroder Extensions</label>
      <sort_order>600</sort_order>
      <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
      <show_in_website>0</show_in_website>
      <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
    </aschroder>
  </tabs>
  <sections>
    <smtppro module="smtppro" translate="label">
      <class>separator-top</class>
      <label>SMTP Pro</label>
      <tab>aschroder</tab>
      <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
      <sort_order>110</sort_order>
      <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
      <show_in_website>0</show_in_website>
      <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
      <groups>
        <general module="smtppro" translate="label comment">
          <label>General Settings</label>
          <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
          <sort_order>10</sort_order>
          <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
          <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
          <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
          <comment><![CDATA[<div style='background-color: #efefef;margin-bottom: 10px;height: 40px;'> <img style='float:left;width: 150px;' src='http://www.aschroder.com/smtppro-logo.png' /> <span style='float:left;font-size: 20px; margin:10px;'>SMTP Pro Email Extension</span> </div> Configure your SMTP connection below. If you have any questions or would like any help please visit <a href='http://magesmtppro.com' target='_blank'>magesmtppro.com</a>.]]></comment>
          <fields>
            <option translate="label">
              <label>Email Connection</label>
              <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
              <source_model>smtppro/system_config_source_smtp_option</source_model>
              <sort_order>10</sort_order>
              <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
              <show_in_website>0</show_in_website>
              <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
            </option>



            <googleapps_email translate="label">
              <label>Google Apps Email Address</label>
              <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
              <sort_order>20</sort_order>
              <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
              <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
              <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
              <depends><option>google</option></depends>
            </googleapps_email>
            <googleapps_gpassword translate="label comment">
              <label>Google Apps Password</label>
              <comment><![CDATA[Input your Google Apps or Gmail username and password here. For configuration recommendations please see the guide at <a href='http://magesmtppro.com' target='_blank'>magesmtppro.com</a>]]></comment>
              <frontend_type>password</frontend_type>
              <backend_model>adminhtml/system_config_backend_encrypted</backend_model>
              <sort_order>23</sort_order>
              <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
              <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
              <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
              <depends><option>google</option></depends>
            </googleapps_gpassword>

              <sendgrid_email translate="label">
                  <label>SendGrid Username</label>
                  <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                  <sort_order>20</sort_order>
                  <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                  <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                  <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                  <depends><option>sendgrid</option></depends>
              </sendgrid_email>
              <sendgrid_password translate="label comment">
                  <label>SendGrid Password</label>
                  <comment><![CDATA[Input your SendGrid username and password here. For more information visit <a href='http://sendgrid.com' target='_blank'>SendGrid</a>]]></comment>
                  <frontend_type>password</frontend_type>
                  <backend_model>adminhtml/system_config_backend_encrypted</backend_model>
                  <sort_order>23</sort_order>
                  <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                  <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                  <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                  <depends><option>sendgrid</option></depends>
              </sendgrid_password>



            <ses_access_key translate="label">
              <label>Amazon SES Access Key</label>
              <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
              <sort_order>20</sort_order>
              <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
              <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
              <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
              <depends><option>ses</option></depends>
            </ses_access_key>
            <ses_private_key translate="label comment">
              <label>Amazon SES Secret Key</label>
              <comment><![CDATA[Amazon SES support in SMTP Pro is limited and best suited to development and testing purposes. For a full integration with region selection, error/bounce logging and send statistics please see the premium extension: <a href='http://magesend.com' target='_blank'>MageSend</a>]]></comment>
              <frontend_type>password</frontend_type>
              <backend_model>adminhtml/system_config_backend_encrypted</backend_model>
              <sort_order>23</sort_order>
              <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
              <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
              <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
              <depends><option>ses</option></depends>
            </ses_private_key>

            <smtp_authentication translate="label">
              <label>Authentication</label>
              <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
              <source_model>smtppro/system_config_source_smtp_authentication</source_model>
              <sort_order>20</sort_order>
              <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
              <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
              <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
              <depends><option>smtp</option></depends>
            </smtp_authentication>
            <smtp_username translate="label">
              <label>Username</label>
              <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
              <sort_order>23</sort_order>
              <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
              <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
              <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
              <depends><option>smtp</option><smtp_authentication separator=",">login,plain,crammd5</smtp_authentication></depends>
            </smtp_username>
            <smtp_password translate="label">
              <label>Password</label>
              <frontend_type>password</frontend_type>
              <backend_model>adminhtml/system_config_backend_encrypted</backend_model>
              <sort_order>26</sort_order>
              <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
              <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
              <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
              <depends><option>smtp</option><smtp_authentication separator=",">login,plain,crammd5</smtp_authentication></depends>
            </smtp_password>
            <smtp_host translate="label">
              <label>Host</label>
              <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
              <sort_order>29</sort_order>
              <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
              <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
              <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
              <depends><option>smtp</option></depends>
            </smtp_host>
            <smtp_port translate="label">
              <label>Port</label>
              <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
              <sort_order>32</sort_order>
              <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
              <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
              <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
              <depends><option>smtp</option></depends>
            </smtp_port>
            <smtp_ssl translate="label comment">
              <label>SSL Security</label>
              <comment><![CDATA[Custom SMTP servers can be configured in this section. For more information about these configuration options and troubleshooting advice please see <a href='http://magesmtppro.com' target='_blank'>magesmtppro.com</a>]]></comment>
              <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
              <source_model>smtppro/system_config_source_smtp_ssl</source_model>
              <sort_order>35</sort_order>
              <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
              <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
              <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
              <depends><option>smtp</option></depends>
            </smtp_ssl>

          </fields>
        </general>

        <debug module="smtppro" translate="label comment">
          <label>Logging and Debugging</label>
          <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
          <sort_order>50</sort_order>
          <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
          <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
          <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
          <comment>Please only use these settings if you are a software developer or server admin.</comment>
          <fields>
            <logenabled translate="label comment">
              <label>Log Emails</label>
              <comment>This will log all outbound emails. View from System->Tools->SMTPPro - Email Log.</comment>
              <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
              <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
              <sort_order>40</sort_order>
              <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
              <show_in_website>0</show_in_website>
              <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
            </logenabled>
            <cleanlog translate="label comment">
              <label>Clean Email Logs</label>
              <comment><![CDATA[If this is set to yes, old entries will be deleted from email log. Cron is required and log cleaning must be enabled in system/log/enabled for this to work.]]></comment>
              <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
              <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
              <sort_order>50</sort_order>
              <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
              <show_in_website>0</show_in_website>
              <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
              <depends><logenabled>1</logenabled></depends>
            </cleanlog>
            <cleanlog_after_days translate="label">
              <label>Email Log Days Kept</label>
              <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
              <sort_order>60</sort_order>
              <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
              <show_in_website>0</show_in_website>
              <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
              <depends><cleanlog>1</cleanlog><logenabled>1</logenabled></depends>
            </cleanlog_after_days>
            <log_debug translate="label">
              <label>Enable Debug Logging</label>
              <comment><![CDATA[If yes, a log file will be written with debug information.]]></comment>
              <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
              <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
              <sort_order>70</sort_order>
              <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
              <show_in_website>0</show_in_website>
              <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
            </log_debug>
            <test translate="label comment">
              <comment>Save settings before running this test.</comment>
              <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
              <frontend_model>Aschroder_SMTPPro_Block_Adminhtml_Test</frontend_model>
              <sort_order>80</sort_order>
              <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
              <show_in_website>0</show_in_website>
              <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
            </test>
          </fields>
        </debug>
        <esp module="smtppro" translate="label">
              <label>Compatible Email Services</label>
              <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
              <sort_order>70</sort_order>
              <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
              <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
              <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
              <fields>
                  <logenabled translate="label">
                      <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                      <frontend_model>Aschroder_SMTPPro_Block_Adminhtml_Table</frontend_model>
                      <sort_order>40</sort_order>
                      <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                      <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                      <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                  </logenabled>
              </fields>
          </esp>
      </groups>
    </smtppro>
  </sections>
</config>
```

Comment: can you post your system.xml ?

Comment: Try manually adding the extension

Comment: I've tried but it doesn't work

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this issue?

Comment: did you check the namespace name and module name is correct..?

Answer (score 1):

Try to flush the cache, then log out and finally log in again.